# How to Bind datalist in clientside using javascript and jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

How to Bind Datalsit in clientside using javascript and Jquery.I am using Webservice,if the ajax have success I want to bind the `Datalist`.I tried some code

```
function succes(response) {
    var value = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xvalue = $(value);
    debugger;
    var products = xvalue.find("tblProddetails");
    var repeatColumns = parseInt("<%=dlViewProd.RepeatColumns == 0 ? 1 : dlViewProd.RepeatColumns %>");
    var rowCount = Math.ceil(products.length / repeatColumns);
    var i = 0;
    while (i < repeatColumns * rowCount) {
        var table = $("[id*=dlViewProd] tr").eq(0).clone(true);
        for (var j = 0; j < repeatColumns; j++) {
            var prod = $(products[i]);
            if (prod.length == 0) {
                $("table:last", table).remove();
            }
            else {
                $("#img1", table).html($(this).find("ProductImage").text());
                $("#lblPrice", table).html($(this).find("ProductPrice").text());
                $("#lnkID", table).html($(this).find("ProductName").text());
                $("#dlViewProd").append(table).append("<br/>");
                table = $("#dlViewProd").eq(0).clone(true);
            }
            i++;
        }
        $("[id*=dlViewProd]").append(table);
    }
    $("[id*=dlViewProd] tr").eq(0).remove();
    $("[id*=dlViewProd]").show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this suggest you use it,there is an example in the demo

https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Comment: The link is given by you is not working.Give Some Other Ideas.